# Extract date from string

Tags: c#

i want to extract date from string.String is a combination of date and some text attached with it but date format changes for example 1. 12/2/2014 12:00:00 AM day one 2. Mon 12 Sept 2014 day two form these two format how i can extract date and convert it in to datetime in c#.

Comment: What are the two strings? Can you show them with proper formatting?

Comment: example given as 1 and 2 are the two string i cant use regex format changes run time

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ParseExact`/`TryParseExact` with an array of allowed formats:

```
string strDate1 = "12/2/2014 12:00:00 AM";
string strDate2 = "Mon 12 Sep 2014";  // it was a friday ;)
string[] allowedFormats = { "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "ddd dd MMM yyyy" };
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate1, allowedFormats, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine("strDate1 parsed successfully: " + dt); 
}
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate2, allowedFormats, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine("strDate2 parsed successfully: " + dt);
}
```

However, Mon 12 Sep 2014 cannot be parsed because it was not a monday but a friday.

If the strings also contain "garbage" you need to remove it first. You could use following LINQ-query which uses the format-strings' `Length` to get the relevant part of the string:

```
string[] dateStrings = { "12/2/2014 12:00:00 AM garbage garbage", "Fri 12 Sep 2014garbage" };
string[] allowedFormats = { "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "ddd dd MMM yyyy" };
DateTime dt = default(DateTime);
var dates = from dateString in dateStrings
            from format in allowedFormats
            where format.Length <= dateString.Length
            let datePart = dateString.Substring(0, format.Length)
            where DateTime.TryParseExact(datePart, format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
            select dt;
DateTime[] validDates = dates.ToArray();  // both dates parsed successfully
```

Comment: strDate1 is like strDate1="1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM asas" and strDate2="Mon 23 1 dec 2014 asasas" so it not working

Comment: @GaneshGadekar: then remove the garbage first, `asas` is not enough to determine the rules.

Comment: yes you are right but i have same problem date comes attached with description.

Comment: @GaneshGadekar: have a look at my edited answer.